# C# Discord webhook, sending an image and putting text on that image with

Tags: c#, discord, webhooks

As the title states, I want to send a discord webhook and put variables on an image. How can I do this? It should also delete the other one and post it again, or just edit the message, whatever is easier.

Currently I am using the following code to send messages to Discord using a webhook, which works.

````
string discordWebhook = "MYWEBHOOKURL";
string message = "Sent from code!";
string discordMessage = "{\"content\": \"```" + message + "```\"}";
 
webrequest.Enqueue(discordWebhook, discordMessage, callback, this, RequestMethod.POST, new Dictionary<string, string> { ["Content-Type"] = "application/json" });
    ```

Thanks in advance! If there are any questions, let me know!


[Example image of what I want to achieve][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOViU.png
````